# slug its not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want url slug like this

> tkd/index.php/article/77/Kejurnas-2013

but when i click button like this

> tkd/index.php/article/77/Kejurnas%202013

what wrong with my code. this is my view

```
<div class="post-buttons-wrap">
                          <div class="post-buttons">
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/article/' . intval($dt->id) . '/' . e($dt->slug)) ; ?>" class="ui black label">
                                Read More
                              </a>
                          </div><!-- end .post-buttons -->
                      </div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function index()
{

    $this->data['berita'] = $this->mberita->get_berita();
        $this->data['halaman'] = $this->mhalaman->get_profil();

        dump('Page!');
        // Fetch the page template
        $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_by(array('slug' => (string) $this->uri->segment(1)), TRUE);
        count($this->data['page']) || show_404(current_url());

        // Fetch the page data
        $method = '_' . $this->data['page']->template;
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            $this->$method();
        }
        else {
            log_message('error', 'Could not load template ' . $method .' in file ' . __FILE__ . ' at line ' . __LINE__);
            show_error('Could not load template ' . $method);
        }
    $this->data['contents'] = $this->data['page']->template;
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper_mahasiswa', $this->data);
}
```

please help me what to do. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the helper "URL" and use the functions "url_title()" and "convert_accented_characters()" if you need to convert some special characters.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html for more info

Example: 
In your controller code, you will capture your form inputs. then you have to create the slug with a line like this:

```
$event['slug'] = url_title(convert_accented_characters($event['eventName']),'-',TRUE);
```

This line will return you a slug separated by "-", setting all the words to lowercase and deleting all special characters too.

Comment: Always in the controller. You have to pass a String parameter. This string will be the name that you want to convert to slug. then, you can save the slug to your DB and call it into your view.

Comment: i am newbie am not understand. can you make me example code?

Answer (score 0):

try this- use rawurlencode while working with strings in url-

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/article/' . intval($dt->id) . rawurldecode('/') . e($dt->slug)) ; ?>" class="ui black label">
                                Read More
                              </a>
```

Comment: m sorry! Put that in single quotes. it will be rawurlencode('/').

Comment: url become like this http://localhost/tkd/index.php/article/77%2FKejurnas%202013 how?

Comment: its not working url its same like this http://localhost/tkd/index.php/article/77/Kejurnas%202013

Comment: i try this but not working <?php echo base_url('index.php/article/' . intval($dt->id) . urldecode('/') . $dt->slug) ; ?>

Comment: ok. dont use base_url(), instead provide the complete path, perhaps that will work

Comment: i try like this <?php echo 'index.php/article/' . intval($dt->id) . urldecode('/') . $dt->slug ; ?> but its same. how?